# How to pass initial value to a Notifier using family modifier?

Tags: flutter, riverpod, flutter-riverpod

This is my `Notifier`:

```dart
class Counter extends Notifier<int> {
  final int initial;
  Counter(this.initial);

  @override
  int build() => initial;
}
```

I need to pass `initial` value to it, but I'm unable to do that using the `family` modifier anymore.

```dart
// Error
final counterProvider = NotifierProvider.family<Counter, int, int>((initial) {
  // How to get the initial value to pass here?
  return Counter(initial);
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The syntax for using `family`/`autoDispose` using `Notifier`/`AsyncNotifier` is different. You're supposed to change the inherited type

So instead of:

```dart
final provider = NotifierProvider(MyNotifier.new);

class MyNotifier extends Notifier<Value> {
```

With `family` you should do:

```dart
final provider = NotifierProvider.family(MyNotifier.new);

class MyNotifier extends FamilyNotifier<Value, Param> {
```

And the same reasoning applies with `autoDispose`.

Comment: Can this be done with the build_runner?

Answer (score 6):

To add to @Rémi Rousselet's answer, the way to do this using generators (which is the [recommended way of using riverpod](https://docs-v2.riverpod.dev/docs/about_code_generation#:%7E:text=When%20using%20Riverpod%2C%20code%20generation%20is%20completely%20optional.%20It%20is%20entirely%20possible%20to%20use%20Riverpod%20without.%0AAt%20the%20same%20time%2C%20Riverpod%20embraces%20code%20generation%20and%20recommends%20using%20it.)) is as follows:

```dart
import 'package:riverpod_annotation/riverpod_annotation.dart';

part 'counter.g.dart';

@riverpod
class Counter extends _$Counter {
  @override
  int build(int initial) => initial;
}
```

Comment: That's what I've been looking for

Comment: @SzymonKowaliński glad it was useful