# How to create an AutoDisposeAsyncNotifierProviderFamily in Riverpod?

Tags: flutter, provider, riverpod

As the question implies, I am trying to create an AutoDisposeAsyncNotifierProviderFamily. I currently have this:

```dart
final participantProvider = AsyncNotifierProvider.autoDispose.family<
    ParticipantNotifier,
    Map<String, List<String>>,
    String
  >((ref, id) => ParticipantNotifier(id));

class ParticipantNotifier extends AsyncNotifier<Map<String, List<String>>> {
  ParticipantNotifier(this.id);
  final String id;

  @override
  FutureOr<Map<String, List<String>>> build() {
    // Get some participants for this event's id
  }
}
```

(extra indents and linebreaks added for readability). However, I get the error: `The argument type 'ParticipantNotifier Function(dynamic, dynamic)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ParticipantNotifier Function()'`. I don't get why the parameter has type `ParticipantNotifier Function()` even if I add the family modifier. With some other simpler providers I successfully created Families with a similar syntax. Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer: the Notifier itself has to be defined as

```dart
class ParticipantNotifier
    extends AutoDisposeFamilyAsyncNotifier<Map<String, List<String>>, String> {
```

So it needs to extend `AutoDisposeFamilyAsyncNotifier`

Answer (score 3):

Following OP's answer (as well as this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74248644/13062243) by Remi), we'll also need to remove the constructor and add the input to the build method.

Here's the full code for this example:

```
final participantProvider = AutoDisposeAsyncNotifierProviderFamily<
  ParticipantNotifier,
  Map<String, List<String>>,
  String>(ParticipantNotifier.new);

class ParticipantNotifier
    extends AutoDisposeFamilyAsyncNotifier<Map<String, List<String>>, String> {

  @override
  FutureOr<Map<String, List<String>>> build(String arg) {
    // Get some participants for this event's id
    return {'id': [arg]};
  }
}
```